# How do I set a Custom Welcome Message on a course without self-enrollment?

Tags: moodle

I have a course with self-enrollment and have successfully set a Custom Welcome Message on it.

I have another course with PayPal enrollment (and manual enrollment). I do not see the same configuration page to set a Custom Welcome Message on this one. Can someone tell me how to do this please?

I'm using MoodleCloud, which is at Moodle v3.2.

Comment: What Moodle version do you have?

Comment: I'm using MoodleCloud, which is at 3.2

Comment: And about to be upgraded to 3.3 at end of May if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the PayPal enrollment in Moodle v3.0 and it simply does not have a Custom Welcome Message functionality implemented. The Custom Welcome Message function has been implemented only in the self-enrollment plugin.
Details: the self-enrollment plugin has a function called `email_welcome_message()` (Send welcome email to specified user), which in turn will be called when a user enrols him/herself.

However, in the settings page of the PayPal plugin:

*Home->Site administration->Plugins->Enrolments->PayPal*

you could check the checkbox "*Notify students*" in order to get students notified via an email when they've been enrolled via PayPal. I did not test this, though.

Comment: Thanks, I see the checkbox. What will the email that is sent to them contain though?

Comment: The email will contain a standard welcome text, defined in lang/en/moodle.php (look for the key 'welcometocoursetext'), which I can reproduce here: 'Welcome to {$a->coursename}!

If you have not done so already, you should edit your profile page so that we can learn more about you:

  {$a->profileurl}';

Comment: You could of course change the welcome text, if you want, and adapt it to your necessities, although this would be a core change in the PayPal plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't change the standard welcome text because MoodleCloud doesn't allow that. This is why I was trying to set a Custom Welcome message since that is something I do have control over in MoodleCloud.

Comment: Ok. I do not see other solutions, at the moment. If the system does not offer a proper function, and if you cannot change the code, there seem not to be a way to get to a solution.

Comment: I agree - seems I am stuck. Thanks for your help, at least I know to stop looking now!

Comment: No problem. If you feel I gave a good answer, you can accept it. I do not know MoodleCloud: is it possible to install new plugins there? If yes, I could come out with some solutions.

Comment: MoodleCloud is deliberately restricted so you cannot add plugins.

Comment: OK. The only way to change the system seems to be working only on its configuration, which is not enough in this case:-(

Comment: Indeed. Thanks again.